# Why is my Flask SQLite tables not taking the new column I have added?

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am fairly new to Flask and am trying to add a new row to one of my tables (called companies), everything seems to work fine until I try to commit a new set of data to said table. It keeps on showing as *null*, and I am not sure why. I have done the same steps with a different table and column and it worked fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my logic:

```
@app.route('/addcompany')
@login_required
def addCompany():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        company_name = request.form['companyname']
        company_description = request.form['companydescription']
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            filename = '1200px-No-logo.svg.png'

        if file and EXTENSIONS:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

        logo = 'logos/'+filename

        company_website = 'www.google.com' #request.form['companywebsite']


        new_company = companies(description=company_description, company_name=company_name, logo=logo, company_website=company_website)

        try:
            db.session.add(new_company)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'there was an issue adding the company'

    else:


        return render_template('addcompany.html')
```

And here is the db. class:

```
class companies(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    company_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    logo = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    company_website = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

    def __ref__(self):
        return '<Company %r>' % self.id
```

Everything but the company_website column works, any ideas?

[the database with a couple of tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6wtc.png)

Comment: you got an error?

Comment: I didn't get an error, just null columns.

Comment: Are you using SQL_ALchemy, or Flask_SQLAlchemy?

Comment: flask_sqlalchemy

Comment: it is working for me. better the delete the db file and create again

Comment: Thanks for your help, You're correct, all above works. I figured out it was the <form> which was routed incorrectly, all working now.